# Optionally inject a property with Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

With Ninject 2.2, is there any way to optionally inject a property?  In a library I am injecting a performance manager as follows:

```
[Inject]
public IPerformanceManager PerformanceManager
{
    private get; set;
}
```

but on many uses of this library I am not interested in profiling performance, so I want this property to be null.  If I don't declare a binding for IPerformanceManager at all, I get the following error:

> Error activating IPerformanceManager
>   No matching bindings are available,
>   and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:   5) Injection of
>   dependency IPerformanceManager into
>   property PerformanceManager of type
>   PluginDomainManager etc...

OK, fair enough.  So instead, I tried binding it to a method that returns NULL:

```
kernel.Bind<IPerformanceManager>().ToMethod(m => null);
```

But now it gives the error:

> Error activating IPerformanceManager
>   using binding from IPerformanceManager
>   to method Provider returned null.
>   Activation path:   5) Injection of
>   dependency IPerformanceManager into
>   property PerformanceManager of type
>   PluginDomainManager etc...

So an injected property can never be NULL?  I find this surprising.  Any ideas how to accomplish an optional injected property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to decorate your PerformanceManager with the `OptionalAttribute`

This will prevent the Kernel from throwing an Activation exception if it cannot resolve the binder. It will set your dependency to null, just as you want.

Comment: Perfect, thanks... Couldn't find this anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Is there possibility to mark binding as optional so that to not decorate each place with Optional attribute?

Comment: @bsnote, a binding can not be set as optional